# Oracle Left Join not returning all rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following CTE. The first part collects all unique people and the second left joins the unique people with events during a particular time frame. I am expecting that all the rows be returned from my unique people table even if they don't have an event within the time frame. But this doesn't appear to be the case.

```
WITH DISTINCT_ATTENDING(ATTENDING) AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT ATTENDING
FROM PEOPLE
WHERE ATTENDING IS NOT NULL
), -- returns 62 records
EVENT_HISTORY(ATTENDING, TOTAL) AS
(
SELECT  C.ATTENDING,
        COUNT(C.ID) 
FROM DISTINCT_ATTENDING D
LEFT JOIN PEOPLE C
ON C.ATTENDING = D.ATTENDING 
AND TO_DATE(C.DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') < TO_DATE('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD') 

GROUP BY C.ATTENDING 
ORDER BY C.ATTENDING  

)

SELECT * FROM EVENT_HISTORY; -- returns 49 rows
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what happens if you remove the `AND TO_DATE(C.DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') < TO_DATE('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD') ` condition?

Comment: @vkp I get 62 rows returned. Initially I had a where clause in there and thought that this was causing the problem from reading around.

Comment: Switch LEFT JOIN to RIGHT JOIN?

Comment: you should `left join` on `people` instead

Comment: @jarlh I get 63 returned. Additional one is a null field from attending

Comment: Is that good or bad, or better or worse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonny

The problem is inthe column "C.ATTENDING", just change for "D.ATTENDING"

```
SELECT  D.ATTENDING,
        COUNT(C.ID) 
FROM DISTINCT_ATTENDING D
LEFT JOIN PEOPLE C
ON C.ATTENDING = D.ATTENDING 
AND TO_DATE(C.DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') < TO_DATE('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD') 

GROUP BY D.ATTENDING 
ORDER BY D.ATTENDING
```

Comment: Thank you - Never thought about the columns, just assumed I was constructing the join incorrectly.

Comment: Change too the "group by" and the "order by" =)

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems too complicated.  I think the following does the same thing:

```
SELECT P.ATTENDING,
       SUM(CASE WHEN TO_DATE(P.DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') < TO_DATE('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD')
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM PEOPLE P
WHERE P.ATTENDING IS NOT NLL
GROUP BY P.ATTENDING 
ORDER BY P.ATTENDING ;
```

Your problem is that you are aggregating by a column in the *second* table of a `left join`.  This is `NULL` when there is no match.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - I agree from the question, I am a big fan of your answers :-) I am building several columns into this to in the end output a data set. I find CTEs easier to read than multiple sub-queries. So it won't be the final end dataset returned. But I ran into this problem very early on. I will be returning 9-10 columns with totals, averages and %s. Is a CTE a decent idea here or would you suggest another method?

Comment: @Jonnny . . . CTEs are fine.  But, you should summarize `people` using `group by` and get the fields that you want from that table.  I think I understand why you are doing the `left join`, but I still find it awkward (and the extra work will affect performance).

Comment: Thanks for your help with this :-)